# How to find algorithm for integer factorization if the prime factorization of the integer is given?

Tags: algorithms, factoring, recursion, prime-factorization

> We're given factorization of an integer $x=p_1 \cdot p_2 \cdots p_k$ where $p_1<p_2<\cdots<p_k$ are prime numbers such that the power of any prime numbers is not greater than $1$. For example $30=2\cdot 3\cdot 5$ is  legal input while $300 = 2^2\cdot 3\cdot 5$ is not a legal input.
>
> Let $f(x)$ be the number of ways to represent $x$ as a product of integers (not necessarily prime numbers). For example, $f(30)=5$ because $$30=30\cdot 1=2\cdot 3\cdot 5=2\cdot 15=3\cdot 10=5\cdot 6$$
>
> (order is not important).
>
> What could be an algorithm which calculates $f(x)$ given $x=p_1 \cdot p_2 \cdots p_k$?

Ideally the algorithm should use dynamic programming principles but most importantly what would be the recursive formula to find $f(x)$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you have specified that no prime appears more than once, your product representations correspond exactly to the [partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set) of the set $\{p_1,p_2,\ldots,p_k\}$.

The number of partitions of a set with $k$ elements is the $k$th [Bell number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number) which form sequence [A000110](https://oeis.org/A000110) in OEIS.

Comment: Here is an article about this problem: http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/rota2.pdf $\qquad$

Comment: @Henning Makholm, And what will be the result, if any power of primes in factorization is allowed?